# Unresolved reference - binding view - kotlin android extension

Tags: android, view, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

In my project I have multiple modules and in that case I have created layout where I have included layout from another module.
Now when I'm trying to call some view from included layout by using Kotlin Android Extensions I'm getting an error during build process

```
Unresolved reference: <object_name>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve that or maybe that extensions does not allow to call views from included layout?